# Extra parenthesis required for ternary statement

Tags: javascript, ternary

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var cond = true;
var res1 = "400" + cond ? "%" : "px";
var res2 = "400" + (cond ? "%" : "px");
```

the result is as follows:

```
res1 = "%";
res2 = "400%";
```

Am I missing something?  It seems like both statements should equal "400%" - why is the first one not picking up the first part of the string?

Comment: Because it's using `"400" + cond` as the condition statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [JavaScript's operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), conditional is lower than addition (well, concatenation, in this case). `"400" + cond ? "%" : "px"` is equivalent to `("400" + cond) ? "%" : "px"`.